# prevent NULL in mysql view, de-normalization

Tags: mysql, null, view

I´d love to do something like this, but with a working syntax of course :)

```
MIN(CASE WHEN col=2 
THEN CASE WHEN answer IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE answer END END)
```

i am trying to prevent a view from getting NULL values and use zeros instead.
Here is my SELECT query that creates the view:

```
SELECT result,question_id,
MIN(CASE WHEN col=1
THEN answer
END) AS col1,
MIN(CASE WHEN col=2 
THEN answer
END) AS col2,
MIN(CASE WHEN col=3
THEN answer
END) AS col3
FROM answers 
GROUP by result,question_id
```

Basically I get a nice result that looks like this

```
result   question_id   col1   col2   col3
1            2          10     20      70
2            2          80     20     NULL
3            3          0     100       0
```

I do not have any performance problems and the original table is updated regularly that´s why I'd love to stay with the view as opposed to a sp. The table that you see disperse a relational structure of a survey that surveys probabilities. That the cols of every row have to add up to 100.  If someone is really sure that something e.g. col3 wont happen he can either fill in 0 to the other form fields or leave the field blank. The form validator checks only if it all adds up to 100. If the field is left blank, the relational there is NO entry in the relational table, so the dispersed view writes a NULL.

I´d love to make it write a "0" but i do not know how! Thx for any suggestions in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `IFNULL(..something...,0)`

---

Apparently have to spell it out:

```
IFNULL(MIN(CASE WHEN col=3 THEN answer END),0)
```

Comment: where should i use that code, the "obvious" does not work:

... THEN IFNULL(answer,0) :(

The problem is that the original table does not have an entry when the user left it blank, there is no record at all, that´s why the view becomes NULL, not because the value in the original table is NULL.

Comment: +1 for spelling it out :) . Thx for your time Wrikken. 
Btw I found a really "strange" behavior. When I changed my original query to MAX(CASE WHEN col=2 
THEN answer ELSE 0) , it worked too, but I don't get why MAX / MIN suddenly had an impact. In other words your solution is of course better.. but I dont understand what happened to mine...

Comment: The `ELSE 0` would prevent having a NULL in the resultset to have to choose from, unless there's an answer column with a NULL  value

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name AS Name, category AS Category, IF(winter>500, "Sells", "Slow") AS Trend FROM sales;
```

That was from http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQL/Flow-Control/UseIFinselectclause.htm